# Prove or disprove: $|\sin z|<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove: $|\sin z|<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$

I took some good advice and try $z=iy$ for $y\in \mathbb R$, so

$$\sin z= \sin iy = \frac{e^{i(iy)}-e^{-i(iy)}}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{e^{-y}-e^y}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{i(e^y-e^{-y})}{2}$$

Now say $y=5$

$$\sin z=\frac{i(e^5-e^{-5})}{2}=74.203i$$

so $|\sin z|=74.203 >1$. And that's it?

Comment: Hint: what if $z=iy$ where $y$ is real?

Comment: Your inequality is on complex numbers, and in $\mathbb{C}$ you do not have $-1\leq \sin z\leq 1$, and indeed you do not have strict inequality. You can read here a bit about complex functions: http://www.milefoot.com/math/complex/functionsofi.htm

Comment: You are right:  the simplest way to disprove this is to take $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  However, I think you or your professor has made a typo, and actually wants to look at $|\sin(z)|\leq 1$.  For this, the other answers suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing you really ought to think about is your statement
$$-1\le\sin z\le1$$
for complex $z$.  You should realise that since the sine of a complex number is in general complex, this statement is not so much wrong as **meaningless**!  There is no useful way of defining one complex number to be less than or greater than another.

As for the specific question you asked, if you simplify
$$|\sin(iy)|$$
where $y$ is real, you should be able to show that it can be as large as you like and does not have to be less than $1$.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

To kill a mouse with a cannon --- the only bounded holomorphic functions are constants.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality you wrote has only been proven when $z$ is real.

The definition of $\sin z$ which extends it to complex numbers is
$$
\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\qquad z\in\mathbb C
$$
So, are there any values of $z$ that can make the above expression very large? For example, for what values of $z$ is $e^{iz}$ large?

Answer (score 2):

The statement in indeed false. But also $|\sin z| \le 1$ would be false; in fact $\sin z$ is **not** bounded if $z \in \mathbb C$.

This can be shown in several ways, for example by writing the $$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{iz}}{2i}$$ and choosing an imaginary $z$.

I don't know if you know about holomorphic function, but note that the [Liouville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) theorem implies that every bounded entire function must be constant. 
Since $\sin z$ is entire, if it was bounded then it would have to be constant but that is clearly false.

This is admittedly using a nuke to kill a fly though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well considering z=pi/2 would do the job were here z is a complex number where its imaginary part is zero!
Dont forget that R is a subset of C

Answer (score 1):

Just see this.

$$ \sin(z) = \sin(x+iy) = \sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y).  $$

Can you bound it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we obviously know that $-1 \leq \sin (x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But in $\mathbb{C}$ we have the introduction of the imaginary axis. I would suggest you try a few $z$'s along the imaginary axis. You might get something more substancial.